# Using Javascript and Underscore.js, how can I compare 2 arrays and replace properties if a match?

Tags: javascript, arrays, node.js, underscore.js

I have 2 arrays like so:

```
var arrayOne = [
    {page:'1',tags:['foo','bar']},
    {page:'2',tags:['oh','boy']}
];
var arrayTwo = [
    {page:'1',tags:['go','out']},
    {page:'9b',tags:['red','blue','green']}
];
```

I want to compare the two arrays, and if the `page` property is the same, replace the `tags` property in `arrayOne` with the `tags` property from `arrayTwo`.

So given the example arrays above, only the tags for `page: 1` of `arrayOne` would get replaced with `page: 1`'s values from `arrayTwo`.

I'm thinking I can do this with `underscore.js`, but I'm struggling to see how.

Ideas?

Comment: Are you missing a `'` from the final entry in `arrayTwo`? Is that a typo here, or in your real code?

Comment: Why do you have arrays of JSON strings?

Comment: Sorry, been in JSON hell lately, it's just how my brain is stuck, and I'm working with returned data from MongoDB/Mongoose. Yes, just a typo.

Comment: So are they JSON strings or are they actually unpacked into JavaScript objects?

Comment: I have edited the original question to fix the JS array syntax.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to do what I needed by using Underscore's `_each` by doing one inside of another like so ( http://jsfiddle.net/4JP7g/ ) :

```
var arrayOne = [
    {page:1,tags:["foo","bar"]},
    {page:2,tags:["oh","boy"]}
];
var arrayTwo = [
    {page:1,tags:["go","out"]},
    {page:9,tags:["red","blue","green"]}
];

_.each(arrayOne, function(one){
    _.each(arrayTwo, function(two){
      if(one.page === two.page){
                one.tags = two.tags;  
                console.log (one.tags);            
      }           
    });
});​
```

Answer (score 1):

If you actually have two arrays of JavaScript objects like this:

```
var a1 = [
    {page: '1', tags: ['foo', 'bar']},
    {page: '2', tags: ['oh',  'boy']},
    //...
];
var a2 = [
    {page: '1',  tags: ['go', 'out']},
    {page: '9b', tags: ['red', 'blue', 'green']},
    //...
];
```

Then I'd convert `a2` to a page-to-tags lookup table:

```
var lookup = { }, i, e;
for(i = 0, e = a2[i]; i < a2.length; e = a2[++i])
    lookup[e.page] = e.tags;
```

and then spin through `a1` merging in `lookup` values as you go:

```
for(i = 0, e = a1[i]; i < a1.length; e = a1[++i])
    e.tags = lookup[e.page] || e.tags;
```

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/ambiguous/aDgH7/

If you must use Underscore, you could replace the loops with [`_.reduce`](http://underscorejs.org/#reduce) and [`_.each`](http://underscorejs.org/#each):

```
var lookup = _(a2).reduce(function(lookup, e) {
    lookup[e.page] = e.tags;
    return lookup;
}, { });
_(a1).each(function(e) {
    e.tags = lookup[e.page] || e.tags;
});
```

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/ambiguous/rkMZz/

If you could assume a modernish JavaScript, then the standard [`reduce`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/reduce) and [`forEach`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/forEach) array methods could be used:

```
var lookup = a2.reduce(function(lookup, e) {
    lookup[e.page] = e.tags;
    return lookup;
}, { });
a1.forEach(function(e) {
    e.tags = lookup[e.page] || e.tags;
});
```

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/ambiguous/cy2Qy/

If you actually have arrays of JSON strings then you can mix in `JSON.parse` and `JSON.stringify` calls to unpack and repack the data.

Answer (score 0):

like

```
var arrayOne = [
    '{"page":"1","tags":["foo","bar"]}',
    '{"page":"2","tags":["oh","boy"]}'
];
var arrayTwo = [
    '{"page":"1","tags":["go","out"]}',
    '{"page":"9b","tags":["red","blue","green"]}'
];

var maxLen = Math.max( arrayOne.length, arrayTwo.length ),
    objA, objB;

while( maxLen-- ) {
    objA = JSON.parse( arrayOne[ maxLen ] );
    objB = JSON.parse( arrayTwo[ maxLen ] );

    if( objA.page === objB.page ) {
        objA.tags = objB.tags
        arrayOne[ maxLen ] = JSON.stringify( objA );
    }
}
```

This is pretty much a *perfect world* example. It becomes a little bit more tricky if Array one and two do not contain the same amount of items.

Comment: They most definitely will not contain the same amount of items.

Comment: @k00k: then the above code is unfortunately pretty much useless. In this case you need some unique identifier in both arrays for each entry (this could possibly be the "page" value). So I'd loop over arrayOne and search arrayTwo for a matching entry and if that can be found, replace the "tags" property.

Comment: re: looping - yes, that's pretty much what my question is asking, "What's the best way to do? Using Underscore?"